# How to call a void in my script with parameters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used an item script that I found online that picks up an Item. It was intended for first-person raycasting but I changed it to detect if my player triggers the item. I wanted the item to lock to my player's hand 1 second after the animation plays. I tried invoking but I learned I can't do that with parameters. I then tried Coroutines but they were complicated and I could not get it to work. I made a new void that I invoke after 1 second which I want to start my PickItem void. However, I don't know how to do this. I don't understand how parameters work either.

```
 public int number = 1;
    Animator animator;
    private int i;
    private GameObject[] Item;
    private bool inrange;
    // Reference to the character camera.
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera characterCamera;
    // Reference to the slot for holding picked item.
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform slot;
    // Reference to the currently held item.
    private PickableItem pickedItem;
```

My OnTriggerStay code.

```
 private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Item")
        {
            inrange = true;
            if (inrange == true && (number % 2) == 1)
            {
                // Check if object is pickable
                var pickable = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PickableItem>();

                // If object has PickableItem class
                if (pickable)
                {

                    //Invoke delay after 1 seconds
                    Invoke("delay", 1f);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

My delay void:

```
public void delay()
    {
        number = number + 1;





        PickItem();
    }
```

My PickItem void:

```
// I don't under stand this line of code either  
/// <param name="item">Item.</param>
 public void PickItem(PickableItem item)
        {
    
            // Assign reference
            pickedItem = item;
            // Disable rigidbody and reset velocities
            item.Rb.isKinematic = true;
            item.Rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            item.Rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            // Set Slot as a parent
            item.transform.SetParent(slot);
            // Reset position and rotation
            item.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            item.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
            item.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().enabled = false;
        }
```

I know coroutines are probably better in this case but I could not get them working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coroutines make this simple. Use `WaitForSeconds` to create the delay:

```
IEnumerator DelayPickup(PickableItem item)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    number++;
    PickItem(item);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{      
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Item"))
    {
        inrange = true;
        // inrange is true here by assignment, don't need to check again
        if (number % 2 == 1) 
        {
            // Check if object is pickable
            var pickable = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PickableItem>();

            // If object has PickableItem class
            if (pickable)
            {
                StartCoroutine(DelayPickup(pickable));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, they aren't called "voids", they're methods with a return type of `void`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am not very experienced with scripting but you answered quickly, precisely, and even improved my code.